# How to get data uniquely in view from controller on a ajax call

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

This is my ajax request code

```
    function ajaxRequest() {
        var currentIndexDay = $('#fieldValue').text();
        var currentIndexMonth = $('#monthFieldValue').text();
        var companyG = $("#companyGname").val();
        var timeline = $("#timeL").val();
        var month = $("#monthSelect").val();
        var year = $("#yearSelect").val();
        var dateRange = $("#dateR").val();

        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/home/pie_chart",
          data: { day: currentIndexDay, week: currentIndexMonth, companyGroup: companyG, timeline: timeline, month: month, year: year, daterange: dateRange}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $("#test").html(msg);
        });
}
```

on Done function the recieved data will showed on the div which id is **test** which is returned from a controller

Here is my controller

```
public function pie_chart() {       

    $data = $this->Statisticsmodel->pie_data_all_day($day);
    $ap = array();

    if(!empty($data)) {

        foreach($data as $d=>$value){

            if($value->moodstatus == 1 ){
                $ap['Ok'] = $value->total;
            }elseif($value->moodstatus == 2) {
                $ap['Bad'] =$value->total;
            }elseif($value->moodstatus == 0) {
                $ap['Good'] =$value->total;
            }

       }

    }
    echo json_encode($ap);
}
```

So how can i catch the output to use in somewhere else not only in a div

Comment: where you want to use your output?

Comment: In view . I hava to add data to a pie chart

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your controller function  to this :

```
public function pie_chart() {       
    $day= $this->input->post('day') // fetch the post data
    $data = $this->Statisticsmodel->pie_data_all_day($day);
    $ap = array();

    if(!empty($data)) {

        foreach($data as $d=>$value){

            if($value->moodstatus == 1 ){
                $ap['Ok'] = $value->total;
            }elseif($value->moodstatus == 2) {
                $ap['Bad'] =$value->total;
            }elseif($value->moodstatus == 0) {
                $ap['Good'] =$value->total;
            }

       }

    }
    echo json_encode($ap);
}
```

Since the day was not fetched,so the `$data` was empty and you are getting the empty response.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax function like

```
function ajaxRequest(getData) {

    var currentIndexDay = $('#fieldValue').text();
    var currentIndexMonth = $('#monthFieldValue').text();
    var companyG = $("#companyGname").val();
    var timeline = $("#timeL").val();
    var month = $("#monthSelect").val();
    var year = $("#yearSelect").val();
    var dateRange = $("#dateR").val();

    $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/home/pie_chart",
          data: { day: currentIndexDay, week: currentIndexMonth, companyGroup: companyG, timeline: timeline, month: month, year: year, daterange: dateRange},
          success:function(data) {
            getData(data); 
        }
    });
}
```

Use it in div as like

```
ajaxRequest(function(output){
    $("#test").html(output);
});
```

Use it in your chart as

```
ajaxRequest(function(output){
   $('#piechart').piechart({
      data : output
   });
});
```